# Missing tab bar after segue to nested table view controller

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

My goal is to show specified row from `TABLE2` after clicking button from `VC1`

After doing segue from `VC1` to `TABLE1` and then to `TABLE2` my tab bar is missing. I have something wrong with storyboard, or I just must add this tab bar manually after doing segue? I'm doing segue to navigation controller, then I call performSegue from `TABLE1` to `TABLE2`

`TABLE2` after segue looks like:

[image]

But it should looks like:

[image]

Code for `VC1`:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func performSegueTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueFromMainWindow", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueFromMainWindow" {
            let destinationNavigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let targetController = destinationNavigationController.topViewController as? FirstTableViewController
            targetController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Code for `TABLE1`:

```
class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destCtrl = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController
        destCtrl.testLabelText = "hello"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a custom identifier to your SecondTableViewController in Main.storyboard and then assign an IBAction to your button, like below:

```
@IBAction func performSegueButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController?.viewControllers
    let tableNavigationController = tabBarViewControllers?[1] as! UINavigationController
    let firstTableViewController = tableNavigationController.topViewController as! FirstTableViewController
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondTableViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondTableViewController") as! SecondTableViewController
    secondTableViewController.testLabelText =  "Something"
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    tableNavigationController.setViewControllers([firstTableViewController, secondTableViewController], animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **TABLE2** viewController in storyboard.
Make sure to un-check the "Hide Bottom Bar on Push".

OR try to force showing the tab bar.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destCtrl = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController
        destCtrl.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
        destCtrl.testLabelText = "hello"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have unchecked "Hide Bottom Bar on Push", forcing it by code doesn't solve the problem too